# Options missing when creating VM in eSXI

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

I'm trying to create a virtual Linux machine in my eSXI admin page but it keeps defaulting to strange options and won't let me define a CPU, RAM or drives. It's easier to explain by showing a screenshot, see below:

[image: esxi screenshot]

The dropdowns for everything are non-functional. When this does work properly, it has no errors and sets a proper default for everything, while allowing me to assign resources properly.

What is going on here? I have one other VM which is certainly not using all the resources of the server and infact, I had the same issue when there were no VMs at all. I had to reboot the server to create a new one but this shouldn't be a requirement whenever I want to create a new VM.

I'm using a HP Proliant N54L if that matters, esxi 6.5